# With facebook offline acces token send friend request

Tags: facebook

I am playing around all the different apis for facebook friend request..
I want to have any method which can send request for friendship with app_id ,user_id and offline access token of user . Using no java script and no fbml methods..

I want just request to be send friendship request method . 
Is there any get method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Also why would you do that?!
Things to [remember](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/):

> **Usage Notes**
>
> This feature is intended to help users become friends on Facebook with
>   people that they are connected to in real life. You should not use
>   this feature to encourage users to friend other users that they are
>   not connected to in real life. If your app is found to be encouraging
>   this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.

Also Facebook encourage user-initiated actions (refer, [publish_stream permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)):

> However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing
>   model.

Comment: Thanks ,have read about (things to remember) friends dialog on face book dev pages.. But i have only offline access tokens of user stored in the data base and app id to send request.I have redirect uri and uid  to get responce , but for that user has to get authenticated ? if yes any way to solve this  Please ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to allow apps to send friend requests.